# Entity framework : Using summary functions inside a Projection

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to run the following query :

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MyObj1 where t1.id>6 Select New With { _
 .Parent = t, _
  .sash = t.child1.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t2) t2.tp=2).Sum(Function(t3) t3.quantity), _
 .vlh = t.child1.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t3) t3.tp=2).Sum(Function(t3) t3.value) _
}).ToList

( in this query .quantity and .value  have Decimal type.)
```

but I'm getting this error on runtime :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Additional information: The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. 
Either the result type's genericparameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

It's sure that the collection child1 has items that have .tp=2.

What's wrong ?
Thank you !

**Updated :**
these are the tables on database :

```
MyObj1:
  Id      name 
   2       name1
   7       name7
   8       name8

Child1:
   ID      ParentID    TP      Quantity     Value
    1         2         2         7          9
    2         7         2        20         10
    3         7         2         8         11 

( ParentID is the forign key for child1 related to ID field on MyObj )
```

Also , I try the query like this :

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MyObj1 where t1.id>6 Select New With { _
 .Parent = t, _
  .sash = t.child1.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t2) t2.tp=2).Count(Function(t3) t3.quantity), _
 .vlh = t.child1.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t3) t3.tp=2).Count(Function(t3) t3.value) _
}).ToList
```

and has no problem. so I think maybe the problem is the SUM function.

**Update :**
This is working without errors :

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MyObj1 where t1.id>6 Select New With { _
 .Parent = t, _
  .sash = t.child1.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t2) t2.tp=2).Sum(Function(t3) Ctype(t3.quantity,System.Nullable(of Decimal)), _
 .vlh = t.child1.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t3) t3.tp=2).Sum(Function(t3) Ctype(t3.value,System.Nullable(of Decimal)) _
}).ToList
```

But I have problems because this method doesn't return any value on the Sums for those parent's items that doesn't have any child in Child1 collection , for example For the Item on Myobj1 with id=8 there's no child1's item , but in this case I want to return a 0 as a sum.
What can I do ?
Thank you !

Comment: What are the data types of `t3.quantity` and `t3.value`?  By the way, should that first `Sum` parameter not logically be `t2` rather than `t3`?

Comment: One of t2, t3 is null !!  >> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. So Check this !

Comment: Please , see the table's values in my first post.

Comment: "It's sure that the collection child1 has items that have .tp=2" - not true (now that you've updated to show real values). While it's true that `context.Child1` `DbSet` has items that have `.tp=2`, the expression `t.child1` is _not_ the same thing ... this is a navigation property on your `MyObj1` class, and most certainly does _not_ have items with ".tp=2" (or any other value) for the `MyObj1` instance with `Id==8`. In fact, depending on how you implement this (which we've no idea, because you didn't include that code), it's possible t.child1 is `null`. Did you attempt the fix from my answer?

Comment: I think it's time we stepped back and considered posting a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): we're only guessing at the parts of your code that you've not included, and they appear to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MyObj1
           Where t.id > 6
           Where Not (t.child1 Is Nothing)
           Select New With {}).ToList
```

Hard to tell with just the code you've posted, but it appears something before you get into the LINQ statements is already `null` (i.e., `Nothing`).

**EDIT**

Sorry, just couldn't hack it in VB anymore ... switching to C# - hoping this is what you're looking for (because it's EF, I don't have an actual DB, and don't have time to set up an in-memory data store, it's not tested with your actual data):

```
(from t in context.MyObj1s
 where t.Id > 6
 from c in context.Child1s
 where c.ParentId == t.Id
 where c.Tp == 2
 group new { Quantity = c.Quantity, Value = c.Value } by t into g
 select new
 {
    Parent = g.Key,
    Sash = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
    Vlh = g.Sum(x => x.Value),
 }).ToList();
```

This avoids passing the `child1` navigation property on `MyObj1` into a context where it's trying to convert `IQueryable`s into SQL, which `child1` is not (directly).

Comment: Please see the table's values in my first post.

Comment: and I try to run the query as I posted now on my first post , and I have no problem. so maybe the problem is the sum function.

Comment: Yeah, but I've no idea how your version using `Count` is even working ... `Count` is supposed to take no parameter, or a `Func` returning a `bool`, which neither `quantity` nor `value` is a `bool`; `Sum` is the correct method that you should be using, so you shouldn't think `Count` is your salvation here.

Comment: No , I want to use sum , but I use count just for example that the count works and sum doesn't work.

Comment: And I admit, that is odd that `Count` works: if `t.child1` were `Nothing`, it seems `Count` would have the same issue.

Comment: I try your solution , but I get this error on runtime : An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[MyProg.Child1, MyProg, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Comment: Oops ... yeah, that won't render into SQL ... forgot we were working with `IQueryable`s. (And VB is not my "first language".)

Comment: I found this link , but even the method described here doesn't work for me : https://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/queryable-sum-on-decimal-and-null-return-value-with-linq-to-entities/

Comment: Please see my latest update on my first post , if you coluld give me an idea.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The cast to nullable decimals is necessary because of the null values.

If you want zeros in stead of null values you have to add `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MyObj1 _
           where t1.id>6 Select New With { _
              .Parent = t, _
              .sash = t.child1.Where(Function(t2) t2.tp=2) _
                              .Select(Function(t3) t3.quantity), _
                              .DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(), _
              .vlh  = t.child1.Where(Function(t3) t3.tp=2) _
                              .Select(Function(t3) t3.value) _
                              .DefaultIfEmpty().Sum() _
}).ToList
```

This return an `IEnumerable` with a `0` value when there are no results in the subqueries.